# Range.find statement doesn't find a match

Tags: excel, vba

TeamsRange is a 24-element range containing values "1" to "24".  There are no merged cells within that range. I want the find statement to return the address of the cell containing "15", but returns "nothing".  However, the following for-loop finds a match for value "15" in the 15th element of the range.

My question - Why doesn't the find work as I expected?

```
Sub FindaMatch()

Dim NrTeams As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim Nextvs As String
Dim NextvsCell As Range
Dim TeamsRange As Range
Dim SheetName As String

    SheetName = "Day 1 Swiss"
    NrTeams = 24
  
    With Worksheets(SheetName)
        Set TeamsRange = .Range("B1:B" & NrTeams)
    End With

    Nextvs = "15"
    Set NextvsCell = TeamsRange.Find(Nextvs, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            after:=TeamsRange(1), _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If NextvsCell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Found nothing"   ' which it does
    End If
    
    For x = 1 To NrTeams
        Debug.Print x, TeamsRange(x)
        If TeamsRange(x) = Nextvs Then
                Debug.Print "Found!", ActiveSheet.Name  ' Which it does on x=15
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

See the code above with the problem find statement, and for loop to demonstrate that the expected value is in the range.

Comment: What format is column B, general, text, number ?

Comment: Well row 1 was General format, so I painted that format down the whole row and the range.find now works.  No idea what the other cells were, so you got it in one.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sorry - I mean painted down the column.

Comment: Actually I've now realised that my problem was that range.find doesn't work for xlvalues in a hidden range.  I unhid the range to check the column B cell formats, then tested again while the range was not hidden, hence it worked.  On checking various sources on how to use range.find, none seem to point out that it doesn't work on hidden cells, but plenty of posters have tripped up on this.